# broken fetchmail configuration

Tags: mac-osx, email

I'm trying to configure fetchmail on my OSX 10.5.6 box. I've setup my .fetchmailrc as follows:

```
poll my.mailserver.com with proto IMAP 
timeout 30
user "username" is "username" here options ssl keep
```

I'm using a .netrc file to store my usernames/passwords as so:

```
machine my.mailserver.com
login username
password secret
```

However, when I run fetchmail I get the following error:

```
reading message username@my.mailserver.com:1 of 458 (4436 octets)
fetchmail: timeout after 30 seconds waiting for listener to respond.
fetchmail: socket error while fetching from username@my.mailserver.com and delivering to SMTP host localhost
fetchmail: Query status=2 (SOCKET)
fetchmail: Server certificate verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
fetchmail: Server certificate verification error: certificate not trusted
fetchmail: Server certificate verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
fetchmail: Error exchanging credentials
```

It seems fetchmail can login OK but it fails to deliver anything to postfix (which I've verified is up and running by telnetting to localhost:25).

Next I invoked fetchmail with -vv flags to get some extra info about what is happening. I notice the following strange message:

```
Trying to connect to 208.97.132.126/25...fetchmail: timeout after 5 seconds waiting for listener to respond.
fetchmail: 6.3.8 querying my.mailserver.com (protocol POP3) at Tue, 14 Jul 2009 18:20:09 +1000 (EST): poll completed
fetchmail: discarding new UID list
fetchmail: Query status=2 (SOCKET)
```

That IP address is very strange. Shouldn't fetchmail only be trying to connect to localhost for message delivery? A quick nslookup reveals the target host domain is one jankymail-mx1.g.dreamhost.com. wtf?

This is all with out-of-the-box fetchmail install btw -- it's a brand new iMac!
Does anyone have an idea what could be happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ping? Curious if adding smtpaddress helped?

Answer (score 1):

Add the option: `smtphost localhost` or even `smtphost 127.0.0.1` to tell it to deliver to localhost. I have no idea why it is defaulting to something else (is that your entire fetchmail config?).

Actually, that may be it attempting to use ETRN or something; that IP resolves to jankymail-mx1.g.dreamhost.com... is that your mail server?

Also, you may need the `sslcommonname` or `sslfingerprint` option if the certificate is either self-signed or doesn't match the hostname.

Comment: Hi derobert, 

Thanks for your reply. 
Yes, that is my whole config file and no, I have no idea where the IP address comes from. I have no mail server on dreamhost.com; I just want to redirect to localhost.

I've tried setting smtphost localhost, but the problem persists.

Comment: I should add: if I add "smtphost 127.0.0.1" my postfix bounces the forwarded messages with fetchmail: SMTP< 401 4.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax

Do I need to reconfigure postfix somehow?

Comment: Nah, you shouldn't need to reconfigure postfix. Try adding in a smtpaddress <<your-hostname>> to your fetchmail config. Make sure it is something postfix will recognize as local (so it won't attempt a remote delivery)

Comment: ... or even smtpname to specify the full address.